# Block level configuration not available in reaction part of context

Tags: 7

I am new to context. I just want to disable a block for a particular URL. But i don't get block level configuration in reaction part of context. Anything else i have to do for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original context that adds the block you can negate a path by using a Tilde along with your path (in the context condition).

```
e.g. ~your-path
```